# zsh function with fzf selection requires Enter

Tags: zsh, fzf

I wrote a simple zsh function which allows me to select from the `dirs-stack` via `fzf`.

My `.zshrc` looks like

```bash
DIRSTACKSIZE='99'    
setopt PUSHD_IGNORE_DUPS

# change to directory from the dirs stack
fzf-change-dirstack () {
    cd "$(dirs -lv | cut -f2 | fzf )" 
}

zle -N fzf-change-dirstack
bindkey '^[p' fzf-change-dirstack   # shortcut ALT+P
```

It works fine even some improvements have to be done. The only thing which is very annoying for me is that when I use the keybinding I have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> twice to change to the directory.

How can I modify the script to `cd` immediately without typing twice <kbd>Enter</kbd> again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fzf-change-dirstack () {
  local dir
  print -rNC1 -- $dirstack |
    fzf --read0 --print0 |
    IFS= read -rd '' dir &&
    cd -- $dir &&
    zle -I
}

zle -N fzf-change-dirstack
bindkey '^[p' fzf-change-dirstack  # shortcut ALT+P
```

The main point being `zle -I` to `I`nvalidate the prompt when the current working directory has changed, the rest fixing a few other issues in your code so it can work with arbitrary directory names.

In particular:

- `dirs -lv | cut -f2` would fail if any of those directory names contained newline or tab characters. More generally, file paths can be any sequence of non-null bytes. So to pass to `fzf`, you want to use its `--read0` and provided a null-delimited list (here `print`ing `r`aw `N`ull-delimited on `1` `C`olumn).
- If you forget the `--`, then any directory starting with `-` would be a problem (wouldn't happen normally if not for the previous bug¹). [Forgetting it for `print` even introduces command injection vulnerabilities](/a/590210).
- don't forget error handling!

Also note that zsh already has its own dirstack completer when you complete `cd +`<kbd>Tab</kbd>  or just `~+`<kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete dirstack elements as argument to any command, not just `cd`/`pushd`.

For instance, try `cd +`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> after:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
autoload compinit
compinit
```

And navigate with the arrow keys.

(this kind of setting you generally tune with `compinstall`)

---

<sup>¹ For `cd`, unfortunately, `--` doesn't fix all the problems. `-`, `+1`, `-1` for instance are still treated specially by `cd`. Those wouldn't occur as elements of `$dirstack` but may occur as the second TAB-delimited field of some line in the output of `dirs -lv` like after `cd $'foo\nx\t+1\twhatever'`.</sup>